# Energy Needed for Lunar Lander to Ascend?

Tags: launch, the-moon, spacecraft, launch-vehicle, apollo-11

Is it possible to calculate how much energy was expended when the Apollo 11 lunar lander ascended from the Moon's surface to join the Command Module in lunar orbit?

Many relevant parameters for the ascent stage are here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module#Ascent_stage

but I can't figure out how to calculate the energy expended. Any help towards that will be appreciated.

**update:** In response to "*expended energy* or the *energy increase of the lander* (change in potential + kinetic)?" Yes, the *expended energy*. I'd like to compare that to other launch possibilities.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* The [ascent propulsion system... used Aerozine 50 fuel, and N2O4 oxidizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascent_propulsion_system) The amount of energy *expended* is just the [enthalpy of reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_reaction) for that combination times the amount used. However the amount of energy *added to the ascent vehicle* is but a small fraction of that. Engines are used for the force they impart, not the energy they release.

Comment: So do you really want the *expended energy* (mostly into heat and kinetic energy of fast exhaust molecules) or *the energy increase of the lander* (change in potential + kinetic)?

Comment: Yes, the expended energy. I'd like to compare that to other launch possibilities..

Comment: Might find this interesting:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19670026467